# @Angular/CLI is broken

Tags: angular-cli

So everything was working fine, I restarted VSCode to empty the recycle bin and now when I run ng serve I get the following error:

```
Cannot determine versions of "@angular/cli".
This likely means your local installation is broken. Please reinstall your packages.
```

Have tried deleting node-modules/re-installing packages with npm install and clearing npm cache but that doesnt work. However I did notice that Angular CLI both globally and locally was at 10.0.0 while the package.json says that Angular Compiler CLI (among other things) is at 9.1.11.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

delete your global npm module and reinstall it

```
npm -g uninstall @angular/cli
npm -g i @angular/cli
```

Comment: also, delete the node_modules inside your project and install them with `npm i`

Comment: As mentioned in the question I have tried this and it did not yield any results.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall it `npm install -g @angular/cli` use to flag `-g` for a global installation

Comment: restart your computer so